# Booking extension with hourly bookings

Tags: extensions, extension-request

I'm looking for a Booking extension/module with the ability to display a daily view with the ability to click and book specific hours.

Something similar to the attached image.[image]

I've looked at all the popular extensions from Joomla.org but none of them seemed to fit my needs.

I don't mind if it's a 3rd party plugin or a service that I can somehow integrated in my Joomla site, as long as it fits my needs.

Comment: You may need to look at something more like a multi-room system like you'd use for a dentist office or a therapy/massage type system, as opposed to a hotel type booking system. More like a Reservation system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same requirement and use "[Event Booking](http://joomdonationdemo.com/eventbooking/event-calendar)".  The demo doesn't show it well, but think of each of your reservable time periods as an Event.  You can then create recurring events for whatever time periods you want and allow users to register for them.  We have TV studios that producers can reserve for 4 hour blocks.  Each of those blocks is set up as an event with a limit of 1 person that is allowed to register for it.  Once it's booked, there are no more vacancies for that "event", and effectively unavailable to anyone else for reservation.

Answer (score 2):

Vik Appointments has this capability of hourly bookings:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/vertical-markets/booking-a-reservations/vik-appointments

Demo: http://extensionsforjoomla.com/livedemo/vikappointments/

My only gripe is that it doesn't work running on localhost on your desktop computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Yendif Events](https://yendif.com/joomla/item/events.html) for event booking in my Joomla extension which fulfills the above requirements you have mentioned..Check out its
documentation for more details.

https://yendif.com/joomla/events/getting-started.html

Hope this helps you!!!